# GCM intent.getExtras -- how to display only specific data?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

Working on a GCM enabled app and I can receive messages. However the format is showing as Message: Bundle[{message=test, android.support.content.wakelock=3, collapse_key=do_not_collapes,from=3423423}]

How do I specify to only show the message data keypair ?

GCM received message intent

```
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM will be
             * extended in the future with new message types, just ignore any message types you're
             * not interested in, or that you don't recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i + 1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                sendNotification("Message: " + extras.toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "Message: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`extras` is a `Bundle`. [`Bundle` is a Java class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html), with methods [like `getString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29) for accessing individual pieces of data by key, much like a `HashMap`. If you only want the `message`, call `getString("message")` on `extras`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes inside GCMIntentService class you can parse desired key inside method

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message =   intent.getExtras().getString("BUY");

        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a json string, you can parse and get only "message" key.

Comment: While the server sends a JSON string, the name/value pairs in that JSON string are converted into entries in the `Bundle` as seen by the GCM client-side code.

Comment: Yes inside GCMIntentService class you can parse desired key inside method

@Override
 protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
  Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
  String message =   intent.getExtras().getString("BUY");
  
  displayMessage(context, message);
  // notifies user
  generateNotification(context, message);
 }